# AWS API Gateway: Request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

When I tried to hit the request through postman. I am facing the some problem. I set this in the aws authentication in postman:-

"**Access key**:- xxxxxxxxxx

**Secrete key**:-xxxxxxxxxx

**Aws region**:- ap-south-1

**Service name**:- execute-api".

while **POST** i got this error

```
{ "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/dms/api/v1/filestore/file\n\ncontent-length:29940\ncontent-type:multipart/form-data\nhost:e7ffona9b4.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20170714T111258Z\n\ncontent-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date\n15c77e9022d5c4e9de523e7279515d245695c76115ebabe7517119701f9ae963'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20170714T111258Z\n20170714/ap-south-1/execute-api/aws4_request\nb0e6151f24eb3a4aa5520da442bdafe7625a44ed7c15f3109eeb78eef038a6cd'\n" }
```

while **GET** i got this

```
{ "message": "No method found matching route api/v1/filestore/file for http method GET." }
```

In the code I did something like this

```
@RestController
@requestmapping(value = "/v1/filestore")
public class FileUploadController {

@Autowired
private IFileStoreService fileStoreService;

@CrossOrigin
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/file/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and in **application.properties** i set

```
server.contextPath=/api
```

If I was wrong then please lead me the correct argument and help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your requests without security?

Comment: yeah i did that then also same error appear but when i select No Auth and try to hit a get request with postman then `{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}` this appear.

Comment: I mean without security module in your server. Just turn off security to simplify debug, than we could localize issue

Answer (score 0):

Double check these:

1. The key you're assigning to the object doesn't start with a period.
2. There should not be any invisible character while paste.
3. Try to encoding the CopySource with `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: you are talking about which key? what is the CopySource here?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging signature problems can be difficult and there could be multiple problems involved.  Looking over your description, here's one problem I noticed...

In the error message that you're getting back using postman, we have:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature...The Canonical String for this request should have been...content-type:multipart/form-data...`

API Gateway does not support nor correctly handle multipart/form-data